# Band matrix storage offset

Tags: c++, pointers, sparse-matrix

I was trying to understand how to store a band matrix, I found an example in the book "C++ and Object Oriented Numeric Computing" but I cannot figure out what's the purpose of the line **bda[i] += P;** and this also gives me problems when trying to print the band matrix. Here it is:

```
int N = 5; //Matrix of NxN
int P = 1; //Left bandwidth
int R = 2; //Right bandwidth

//Matrix A
double A[5][5] = { { 1, 6, 10, 0, 0 },
        { 13, 2, 0, 11, 0 },
        { 0, 14, 3, 8, 12 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 4, 9 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 16, 5 } };

//Allocate memory for rows
double** bda = new double*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    bda[i] = new double[P + R + 1]; //Allocate memory for cols
    bda[i] += P; //What's the purpose of this?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used for a compact way to store a matrix that has `P` nonzero diagonals to the left of the main diagonal, and `R` nonzero diagonals to the right, with all other elements being zero. For each row, we only allocate space for the `P+R+1` elements around the main diagonal.

The `bda[i] += P` line makes `bda[i]` point to an element on the main diagonal. This can make it more convenient to use the matrix: `bda[i][0]` is on the main diagonal for every `i`, `bda[i][1]` is on the first diagonal to the right, `bda[i][-1]` is on the first diagonal to the left, etc. This allows you to find elements on the main diagonal or near it without having to add `P` each time. Whether this is helpful depends on how you use the matrix.

Note that if you do this, you will need to subtract `P` from `bda[i]` before you `delete[]` it.

Comment: So all what it does is move the the pointer **bda[i]** to point to the element in the main diagonal of every row?

Comment: @BRabbit27: Yes, it's just used for convenience and is not really necessary.

Comment: Oh no!! I just spent the last hour or so trying to convince myself it was really necessary. Is there a way I can explicitly see how the use of that line changes the way the code behaves? something like printing bad[i]?. I mean, I believe what you say haha and I really understand but I would like to see it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BRabbit27: With that line, you'd have code like `bda[i][1]` to access an element on the first diagonal to the right. Without that line, you'd use `bda[i][P+1]` to access the same element. So if you access elements based on how far they are from the main diagonal, having that line in the initialization saves you from adding `P` for each element access.

Comment: Just one more question, related to that offset. When I ask for the value in `bad[0][1]` it is actually asking the value `bad[1][1]` because of the `bad[i] += P` ?? Am I right? So it raises another question, If I actually want the value in `bad[0][0]` I need to ask for `bad[-1][0]` ??

Comment: @BRabbit27: No, `bda[0][1]` and `bda[1][1]` are in different rows. Suppose we have `bda_orig` before the addition and `bda_added` after the addition, so that `bda_added[i] = bda_orig[i] + P`. Then `bda_added[0][1]` would be the same as `bda_orig[0][2]` when `P==1`.

Comment: I don't want to make a mess in this question, I got even more confused now that I saw the way they fill the bda matrix. Should I ask a new question, should I edit this one?

Comment: @BRabbit27: If it's regarding the same issue (why `P` is added to `bda[i]`) then you can edit this question. Otherwise you should create a new one.